# Confused on how to create and use TableModel

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm Creating a program in netbeans I am having a trouble in putting TableModel on my Jtable data which was retrieved from the database using mysql. Is it posible that I can display the current column names into 1 column and and also the data into another column.

From this :

```
        Name   Age   Address

         Juan   15   Home
```

To this:

```
          Name    Juan

          Age      15

          Address  Home
```

Comment: how would it show if there is more than one row?

Comment: Sounds more like list rather then a table

Comment: I do have 2 jtables in my GUI. the first one was to display all the name.. den the other one was to display the data of the row from the first table

Comment: @ScaryWombat in table2 it is just two columns and its row will depend on how many columns it have on table1